# Change html code on server side asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, string

I want to change some string located in html file when it loads. For example, i have a html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>MyTitle</title></head>
<body>
Some Text
<script type='text/javascript'>
/*some script*/
var myString = "TargerInfo";
/*some script*/
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I use `Page_Load` method in code-behind file:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
/*Insert necessary snippet of code*/
}
```

What code should i use to change string "TargerInfo" to "OtherString" ?

**[EDIT]**
Sorry, that I have forgot to mention
I can add any info to html page only in code-behind class, because this page isn't  generated by me. 
I think i should use something like this:

1) load html file

2) find my string

3) replace it

4) send html file

There is an aspx page, but i add only some part of code and other code is added by VS

Comment: Is this an aspx page? Then why not simply add the relevant <% %> tags in the aspx file?

Comment: I can't do it , because html page isn't generated by me.

Comment: @andDaviD you should have mentioned that right at the start - a lot of people have spent their time on the assumption that you had control over the page

Comment: There is an aspx page, but i add only some part of code and other code is added by VS

Comment: @andDaviD you're still not making sense. From what I can gather, the ASPX file is locked and you are not able to edit it in any way, but you have "some" control over the code-behind file for the referenced class?  Can you clarify exactly **what** control you have, as "some part of code" makes no sense at all?

Comment: @freefaller, Ok, I have added EntityEditorWithPicker control to my aspx page. And when I deploy this page on my server, it is added other code in my html page. But i don't know where this code is generated. I only have written such code in my aspx page: <PickerProj:Editor id="Editor" runat="server" MultiSelect="false" ValidatorEnabled="true" MaximumEntities="1" />

Comment: @andDaviD Just for my curiosity, are you actually looking at the "Design" part of the ASPX page in Visual Studio? If so, have you tried clicking on the "Source" button at the bottom of the ASPX designer screen (where it should have "Design | Split | Source")?

Comment: @freefaller, I double click on the apsx file and then add my code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12860/discussion-between-freefaller-and-anddavid)

Comment: `But i don't know where this code is generated. I only have written such code in my aspx page: <PickerProj:Editor id="Editor" runat="server" MultiSelect="false" ValidatorEnabled="true" MaximumEntities="1" />` Are you talking about the HTML generated by the ASP controls once processed? Could you post the markup for the whole page? Perhaps you have a masterpage tied to it adding in some more markup that you can't immediately see...

Comment: @Duane and others - please see my **updated** answer below for an explanation of exactly what the situation was

Comment: @andDaviD Did you manage to get the situation sorted? Would love to hear any updates

Comment: @freefaller, I have solved my problem. I found an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531631/get-html-of-current-page-without-viewstate-asp-net). Look at the answer of LukeH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something (because this seems like a bit of an ASP.NET 101), you have several options...

Create a variable in the code-behind and then use that...

```
protected string _newText = "";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   _newText = "OtherString";
}
```

And then in the ASPX...

```
var myString = "<%=_newText%>";
```

Otherwise you can use the `<asp:Literal>` control

**UPDATE**

After an extensive [chat with @andDaviD](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12860/discussion-between-freefaller-and-anddavid) it turns out that the javascript is in a Master page held in SharePoint Foundation.

The Master page is being referenced in his Content page via the `DynamicMasterPageFile` attribute in the `<%@ Page` directive, and that is why he said he is able to update some part of the code, but not others.

I am still unsure as to whether it is possible for the Master page to be modified (either by himself or an administrator), that is something he needs to find out from the people in charge at his company.  But I believe the adding of a property or method to the Master Page to provide what he needs is the only sensible option.

Comment: I can't do it , because html page isn't generated by me.

Comment: @andDaviD it would have made sense right at the start to point that out!!

Answer (score 2):

You could use inline aspx code tags:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/*some script*/
var myString = "<%= getTargetInfo() %>";
/*some script*/
</script>
```

in codebehind:

```
protected String getTargetInfo()
{
    return "OtherString";
}
```

Comment: I can't do it , because html page isn't generated by me.

Comment: @andDaviD: What does that mean, is this not an aspx page? Then there's also no codebehind.

Comment: There is an aspx page, but i add only some part of code and other code is added by VS.

Comment: @andDaviD:  It conveys no sense to me, you say that your IDE is preventing you from adding code to the aspx page?

Comment: Ok, I have added EntityEditorWithPicker control to my aspx page. And when I deploy this page on my server, it is added other code in my html page. But i don't know where this code is generated. I only have write such code in my aspx page: <PickerProj:Editor id="Editor" runat="server"
            MultiSelect="false" 
            ValidatorEnabled="true" 
            MaximumEntities="1" />

Answer (score 1):

You could use a literal:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     literal.Text = string.Format("var myString = \"{0}\"", targetInfoValue);
}
```

Markup:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>MyTitle</title></head>
<body>
Some Text
<script type='text/javascript'>
/*some script*/
<asp:Literal id="literal" runat="server" />
/*some script*/
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't do it , because html page isn't generated by me.

Comment: What... so where is the markup then? It would have been useful to point this out in the question

Answer (score 1):

You can have it in a hiddenfield in asp.net and change the hidden field in code behind.

Comment: You mean like what you saw here http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/380472/Access-string-value-in-javascript-from-backend-pag ?

Answer (score 0):

in your code behind:

```
public string otherString;


otherString = "some text"  //update the string with the value oyu want.
```

in aspx page put this line in any place you want to see the otherString.

```
<%=otherString%>
```

Comment: I can't do it , because html page isn't generated by me.

Comment: can you explain a bit more please . you write the code behind but not the html ?!im confused

Comment: @ Ozgur Dogus, Ok, I have added EntityEditorWithPicker control to my aspx page. And when I deploy this page on my server, it is added other code in my html page. But i don't know where this code is generated. I only have write such code in my aspx page: <PickerProj:Editor id="Editor" runat="server" MultiSelect="false" ValidatorEnabled="true" MaximumEntities="1" />