# asp.net Gridview control renders into an unnamed <div> tag, how to access it?

Tags: html, asp.net, css, gridview

net gridview and when its is rendered it seems to sit rendered table within and  tag that has not ID or Class.

This div tag is preventing me from locating the gridview where i want it with my CSS. Is there a way to give it the div an ID or Class so that i can position it?

Below screeny shows the rendered html in the IE dev tools

[image]

Below is the ASP.net part

```
<div class="clObjectTitleBanner">
    <asp:GridView
        ID="gvCurrentStageCircsPSTN"
        runat="server"
        EnableViewState="true"
        GridLines="Both"
        CssClass="gvCircsPSTNDash">
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Comment: It's probably avoidable, but why is this stopping you locating it? Isn't it just `.clObjectTitlebanner div`?

Answer (score 3):

You can target this div in CSS using the `.clObjectTitlebanner > div` selector.

If you *really* want to customize the control HTML, you can do that using [ASP.NET Control Adapters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163543.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You can assign id dynamically using jQuery;

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $('#MainContent_gvCurrentStageCircsPSTN').closest('div').attr('id','parent_div');

});
```

And you can access this in css:

```
#parent_div{
background:#DDD;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like solution is to either grab the corresponding `<div>` tag from HTML and replace it as:

```
string html;
html.Replace("<div>", "<div id="+"\"myID\""+">");
```

OR remove the  tag altogether if you are OK with the [CssClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx) property of gridview. However, you must take care to remove the coresponding `</div>` tag too.

```
string html;
html.Replace("<div>", "");
```

So, you need first to grab the complete HTML of page. This you can do by overriding  ***[Render()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20b8wk8d.aspx)*** method, similar to something like:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
       StringBuilder sbOut = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter swOut = new StringWriter(sbOut);
        HtmlTextWriter htwOut = new HtmlTextWriter(swOut);
        base.Render(htwOut);
        string html = sbOut.ToString();
}
```

However, you now really need to work on the logic as to how will you get the exact `<div>` tag that you need. (It worked for me while developing a small utility as I didn't placed any other `<div>` tags at all). Check this : [get HTML of current page without ViewState ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531631/get-html-of-current-page-without-viewstate-asp-net) ,  http://forums.asp.net/t/1394050.aspx

I hope atleast you get the idea.